# RegEx Replace Facebook url

Tags: c#, regex

I am using C# and would like to replace from

```
http://www.facebook.com/pages/somepagename/139629086070406
```

to

```
https://graph.facebook.com/139629086070406/picture
```

What is the pattern to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string subjectString = @"http://www.facebook.com/pages/somepagename/139629086070406";    
string resultString = Regex.Replace(subjectString, @"http://www.facebook.com/pages/.+?/(\d+)", "https://graph.facebook.com/$1/picture", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Answer (score 0):

You really only want the number `139629086070406`.

Try searching for `\d+$` and replacing with `https://graph.facebook.com/\1/picture`.

Note this is incredibly fragile. If the URL doesn't look exactly as described - i.e. if it has GET parameters on the end - it will break.